# Pseudocode for accessing class variables

Tags: pseudocode, class-variables

How should accessing class variables be written in pseudocode?

Just using the variable name is ambiguous since they will not have been defined.

Comment: In what language? Generally, they're the same, but it depends on what form of language you're programming in. Object Oriented, I assume?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when accessing class level variables in any object oriented language, you want to make sure you invoke Accessor/Mutator methods.

Accessors In Pseudocode:

```
Call Accessor Method
Accessor returns a the variables value.
```

As opposed to Mutators :

```
Call Mutator method (setVariable()) and pass necessary parameters.
No value gets returned, although sometimes true or false is returned.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Make sure they're they're class level, and not FINAL. They're usually private as well. Also you should ALMOST always initialize them to a value in the constructor.